# Creating numpy.float64 using eval()

Tags: python, types, numpy, eval

I've looked around, and did not find any information to create numpy.float64 using the built-in `eval` function.

What I'd like is going from something like:

```
In [1]: x = eval("1.0")
In [2]: type(x)
Out[2]: <type 'float'>
```

to:

```
In [1]: x = eval("1.0")
In [2]: type(x)
Out[2]: <type 'numpy.float64'>
```

The real problem is a bit worse than just the simple example above because the argument passed to `eval` is most often a dictionary with many keys and values. So it would not be possible to use something like: `numpy.float64("1.0")`.

To give you concrete real data I'm working with, here is how a string could look like (it is read from a file):

```
data_str = '{"var_x": {"value": 1.23, "error": 0.25, "unit": "unit name"},
            "var_y": {"value": 1e+4, "error": 1.3e1, "log": False},
            "var_z": ["a", {"x":1, "y":2}, (1, 2, 3), None]'
data = eval(data_str)
```

And then, I'd like `type(data["var_x"]["value"])` returns `<type 'numpy.float64'>`

Do you guys have any suggestions. Did I miss an obvious method?

---

**EDIT**

The precision of numbers I will deal with in `data_str` will not be much more than 15-16 digits.
So converting string to `float` or `numpy.float64` does not matter a lot for that purpose only. However these values will be passed to some complex functions, multiplied, divided... therefore to avoid any error propagation, I have to work with `numpy.float64`.
One workaround could be to convert (after `eval`) any `float` to `numpy.float64`, but it would be nice to have a direct interpretation using `eval`.

**EDIT #2**

I'm wondering why this does not work:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = eval("1.4", {"__builtins__":None, "np":np}, {"float":np.float64})
In [3]: type(x)
Out[3]: <type 'float'>
```

I thought by defining "__builtins__" to `None` within eval globals would avoid it to load default definition for `float`, which I redefine within the locals... It seems it is *impossible* to take out (or replace for this matter) builtin types from `eval` namespace (like `float`, `int`...). Any light on this is welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is replicate what `ast.literal_eval()` does, but instead of just executing the AST you could inject calls to the `numpy.float64` constructor first.

Comment: Humm, not sure I got it. You mean copying the source of `ast.literal_eval()` and then modify it to make use of `numpy.float64`?

Answer (score 2):

Your `data_str` looks very close to being valid JSON. In particular, if the `False` were lowercase, then it would be JSON.

It may not be safe to blindly replace all `False` with `false`. But if it is, then you could use [json.loads](http://file:///usr/share/doc/python2.7/html/library/json.html#json.loads) and the very convenient [parse_float](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.load) hook to convert all floats to `np.float64`s:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import re

def parse_float(x):
    return np.float64(x)

def lower(match):
    return match.group(1).lower()

data_str = '''{"var_x": {"value": 1.23, "error": 0.25, "unit": "unit name"},
            "var_y": {"value": 1e+4, "error": 1.3e1, "log": False}}'''

data_str = re.sub(r'(False|True)', lower, data_str)
data = json.loads(data_str, parse_float = parse_float)
print(type(data['var_x']['value']))
# <type 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: Thanks unutby. I'm not korking with JSON, but I'll have a look to it. If indeed my `data_str` is close to JSON (ie. without too many difference) then your solution looks pretty nice. Too bad `eval` does not have a similar feature, does it?.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want numpy scalars?

Comment: It seems it could also handle something like `"var_z": 1.23`, am I right? The only requirement is that any piece of data has to be embedded in '{}', isn't it? So would it be able to handle a thing like `"var_z": ["string", {"x":1, "y":2}, (4, 5, 6)]`?

Comment: It is a scientific code, so it is mainly for precision purposes. I could change the type after interpreting normally the string with `eval`, but I was wondering if there was a direct way to do that. Also, not shown in my example, `data_str` can have some numbers with 13 digits after the dot. I'd like to be sure that I don't loose any precision with conversion.

Comment: Hm, JSON does not recognize `(4, 5, 6)`. It wants `[4, 5, 6]` instead. You may be able to `re.sub` parens with brackets, but this is starting to look ugly.

Comment: Also, `np.float64('0.00000000000001') == float('0.00000000000001')` is `True`, so I'm not sure `np.float64` buys you anything good.

Comment: Yep it was my concern... `data_str` may have a lot of different basic python object (like tuples, list, dict, float, int, bool, ...). Anyway thanks for your answer, anytime I learn something new is useful.

Comment: From the value itself, maybe not. But then working with the number afterward (multiplication, division, transformed with complex functions...) it does matter to have a `numpy.float64` instead of just a `float`. But you're right, for just the interpretation of the string, it may not matter at all, and I may end up converting the `float` myself after.